Does using GPIO15 on ESP32 for my Hall sensor pose any long-term risk?
I’ve read that GPIO15 outputs a PWM signal at boot and is a strapping pin. Currently, my Hall sensor is connected to GPIO15, but I’m wondering if this could cause damage to the sensor in the long run?
Sensor: https://media.digikey.com/pdf/data%20sheets/seeed%20technology/114991177_web.pdf
PINs Source: https://www.flux.ai/p/blog/esp32-pinout-everything-you-need-to-know

We don't know what are the properties of your sensor output and will it damage or not. Even if there is no long-term damage, who knows if it is reliable or not. Please edit in the details of your sensor and where have you read that GPIO15 is a PWM output during boot.

yes, sorry, i have edited my question

the "datasheet" claims that the "Mini. Wokring Voltage" is 4.5v, so will it even work on your 3.3v ESP? If so, that suggest an open collector output, which won't give a darn about a brief low-current pulse on boot.

it works reliably with 3.3v voltage somehow too. So, to be sure, Hall effect sensor output pin can handle low current pulses on boot, yes? Even when water flows and Hall effect sensor generates itself pulses?

A flow sensor low output, connected to a GPIO high output, can cause damage to one or the other, but it is unlikely. However, that's not a good reason to skip mitigation. Since sensor signal frequency is low, a safe way to connect the two is as follows:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
R2 is only necessary if the sensor has an open-collector (or open-drain) output, but it won't hurt to include it anyway. R1 protects the ESP32 I/O by limiting current in case it's an output, but does not significantly affect the actual potentials seen by the MCU.
The flow sensor should be powered from 5V, and the fact that yours seems to work at 3.3V is a bad reason to actually do that. None of the specifications in the datasheet will be met under those conditions. When powering the sensor from 5V, these are correct and safe ways to interface the two components:

simulate this circuit
D1 here allows the sensor to pull the MCU input low, but does not conduct when the sensor output is high. Therefore the MCU input only ever sees about +0.3V or +3.3V. As before, R1 limits current in case of output contention. R2 is again a pull-up for the sensor's open-collector output, and might not be necessary.

simulate this circuit
Here M1/R3 performs level translation between 0V/+5V from the sensor, and the +3.3V/0V expected by the MCU. It also inverts the signal, but that won't affect measurement of its frequency in software.
